# Crear una api con laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Estoy configurando un proyecto de cero con laravel 5.8 instalando passport.

Siguiendo un tutorial para crear una api he hecho todos los pasos y cuando intento acceder a una ruta recibo este error , por más que miro el resultado o el log de laravel no veo el error

Este es el fichero de rutas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este el error que me da al intentar acceder a una de ellas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Has probado la ruta /api/auth/login?

Comment: Tenes que poner Accept: application/json

Comment: @FranciscoGarrido tenias razón era eso estava poniendo mal la ruta. 1000 gracias

Answer (score -1):

en el header content-type creo que deberias colocar application/json. Cuando haces un php artisan route:list obtienes la lista de las rutas u obtienes un error?